# Can We Always Use Plural Verb With Plural Nouns Or Plural Subject 2019

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, plural-forms

I want to know that can we always use a plural verb with a plural subject or a plural noun like take this example -:

> We **are nerd**.

or

> We **are nerds**.

is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Nerd" is a *noun* - not a verb. You have to use the plural "*nerds*" because you are referring to more than one person by using "we".

> We are nerds.

The verb in both your sentences is "are", which *is* the correct plural form when you are speaking about more than one person. If it was one singular person then it would be:

> I am a nerd.

OR

> He is a nerd.

"*Nerdy*" is an *adjective* derived from the word "nerd" - adjectives in English do not take the plural ending, so this would be the same no matter what the subject:

> We are nerdy.
>
> He is nerdy.

Comment: This fails to address the point I made in my answer - "Nerd" can, and is, sometimes used as a collective.

Comment: @MikeBrockington Please can you cite a dictionary definition showing "nerd" as a collective noun? Or a credible example where it is being used properly?

Answer (score -2):

Tricky question!

In this case, you will find that "We are nerds" (plural) is far, far more commonly used, but your first example is also valid if you consider 'nerd' as a group, in the same manner as "We are family" - hence things like https://www.weare-nerd.com/ and https://www.wearenerd.it/

Comment: Sorry that isn't correct - in "we are family", the word "family" is being used as an *adjective*, as in "the family dog". That cannot be compared with the word "nerd", which is not officially an adjective or a collective noun.

Comment: It _is_ correct - if you prefer an alternative, how about "We are Legion" ?

Comment: a common misquote from the bible - the quotation is actually "**My name is Legion**, for we are many". Legion is being used a proper noun. You even capitalised it, so you must know this. And that is kind of a wildcard example, because in the context it is a legion of demons speaking through one man.

Comment: This is wrong. I suppose if you called your band "Nerd" then in that circumstance you could say "we are Nerd", but that isn't what the OP is about. I do hate it when people defend their wrong answers instead of just fixing them and learning, which is what this site is all about.

Comment: "Nerd" can, and is, used as a proper noun, as is "family" - the latter is not always an adjective. Not frequently, but often enough to get 380,000 hits on Google. Taking English usage from any translation of the bible is just weird - "We are Borg" is far more recent and relevant, and "We are Legion" [sic] has passed into common usage.